# How to replace the methode StageHelper.getStages() from java 1.7 to java 11

Tags: java, migration, java-7, java-11, javafx-11

I am migrating an application which using `JavaFX` from `Java 1.7` to `Java 11`.
One of the error that I have is about the method `StageHelper.getStages()` which has disappeared.
I did not find anything to replace it. Do you have a solution to replace this method ?
Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StageHelper` has been always private API, as it was part of `com.sun.javafx.stage`. As such, you should be aware that private API can be changed or removed at anytime without notification.

For Java 1.7 I can't say, JavaFX (2.2?) wasn't open sourced at that time.

For Java 1.8, the `StageHelper.getStages()` method can be found [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/9f49e3b6147f/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/stage/StageHelper.java#l52).

For Java 1.9 however, `StageHelper`, defined [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/stage/StageHelper.java), doesn't include `getStages` anymore.

The reason for that can be found in this issue [JDK-8156170: Clean up Stage and StageHelper](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8156170).

If you read the description, as part of the issue they will:

> Remove `getStages()` and make caller of this method to use public API `Window.getWindows()`.

**Alternatives**

As mentioned in that issue, since JavaFX 9 you have this public method [`Window.getWindows()`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/stage/Window.java#l220), that will

> return a list containing a reference to the currently showing JavaFX windows

Note that a [`Window`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Window.html) can be a `Stage` or a `PopupWindow`, so maybe you can filter them out:

```
List<Stage> stages = Window.getWindows().stream()
            .filter(Stage.class::isInstance)
            .map(Stage.class::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very clear and it works for me ! :)